# Dev C++ Compiled Exe Information

Tags: c++, ide

When I compile my project in Dev C++ how can I get information displayed on the summary page of the exe properties in windows?

I have tried using the "Version Info" tab in project properties with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

You need to associate a resource with the .exe that has a VERSION info structure in it.  This is the same mechanism used to associate an icon with the application as well.